# JavaScript GetTime Function

Tags: javascript, html

My getTime function shows me the current hour, minutes, and seconds without any problem.
My question is how can I call the hours, minutes, and seconds on different spans?
Example

```
 <span id="hours" class="x"></span>
    <span id="minutes" class="y"></span>
    <span id="seconds" class="z"></span>
```

**JavaScript Function**

```
   <script language="JavaScript">

        function getTime() {
            const timeNow = new Date();
            const hours = timeNow.getHours();
            const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
            const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
            let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
            timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
            timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
            timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
            //timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
            return timeString;
        }

        const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('Hour');

        setInterval(() => {
            hoursSpan.textContent = getTime();
        }, 1000);

    </script>
```

Comment: what is `getElementById('Hour')`

Comment: try with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) its more easy to handle time & date

Comment: Note: You can add 0 to number less than 10 without ternary. You can do `":" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Make the variables global to get separate values of hours minutes and seconds. You were using wrong id to get span and the function returns full string so splitted it for only hours

```js
var timeNow = new Date();
            var hours = timeNow.getHours();
            var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
            var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();

        function getTime() {
            timeNow = new Date();
             hours = timeNow.getHours();
             minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
             seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();

            let timeString = '' + ((hours > 24) ? hours - 12 : hours);
            timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
            timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
            timeString += (hours >= 12) ? "" : "";
            //timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
            return timeString;
        }

        const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
         const min = document.getElementById('minutes');
          const sec = document.getElementById('seconds');

        setInterval(() => {
            hoursSpan.textContent = getTime().split(':')[0];
            min.textContent=":"+minutes;
            sec.textContent=":"+seconds;
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hours" class="x"></span>
    <span id="minutes" class="y"></span>
    <span id="seconds" class="z"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First issue**

You have a silly mistake in this line
`const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('Hour');`
There is no element with the id `Hour`. Your `span` element has id `hours`. You need this instead:
`const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');`

**Second issue**

If you plan to use the 3 parts separately, then why join them into a string in the first place? Just make use of the fact that JavaScript functions can return objects!

This looks a lot cleaner!

```
<span id="hours" class="x"></span>
<span id="minutes" class="y"></span>
<span id="seconds" class="z"></span>

<script>
    function getTime() {
        const timeNow = new Date();

        const hours = timeNow.getHours();
        const minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
        const seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();

        let hoursString = '' + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
        let minutesString = ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
        let secondsString = ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;

        return {
            h: hoursString,
            m: minutesString,
            s: secondsString
        };
    }

    const hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
    const minutesSpan = document.getElementById('minutes');
    const secondsSpan = document.getElementById('seconds');

    setInterval(() => {
        const t = getTime();

        hoursSpan.textContent = t.h;
        minutesSpan.textContent = t.m;
        secondsSpan.textContent = t.s;
    }, 1000);

</script>
```

PS: This code could be shortened a lot, but I kept it this way so it's easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!